# i have to run a 2 different project from same ide like netbeans at a same time how to run that anyone suggest me any ideas?

Tags: java

suggest me any idea for running 2 different projects in the same ide like NetBeans but I think I can change my tomcat server port number to run like this but I am not sure can anyone suggest any idea Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify what your problem is

Comment: I am using Netbeans IDE. Now I want to run two different projects at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about NetBeans but I can tell about Eclipse. 1. Open each project in a different instance of the IDE. 2. Set the tomcat port for each of them different and run the servers. By this way you can run the both the projects simultaneously. Example. I am running a node server in one eclipse instance with port 8080 and running a tomcat server in another eclipse instance with port 9080. Both of them running perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You just need to learn how to start tomcat on different port(s). as per your project needs. There is no concern with IDEs. You can use any IDE for code. Tomcat itself a server. You can run it by CMD with different instances.

You can configure your `tomcat` in you **server.xml** file and put 2 services :

```xml
<Service name="app1">
   <Connector port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app1"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="app2">
   <Connector port="8082" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
```